# Return List to View with only unique numbers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

My application returns a list from the table OrderRows like this:

```
 var allOrders = db.OrderRows.ToList();
```

And this is how my class looks like for the OrderRows:

```
    public class OrderRows
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Produktid")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Orderid")]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pris")]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
}
```

The Order class:

```
    public class Orders
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Orderdatum")]
    public DateTime Orderdate { get; set; }
    public int CustomersID { get; set; } 
    public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderRows> OrderRows { get; set; }
}
```

I'm doing a webshop and I have made it very simple. The table can have several OrderID, but when I pass the list to the view, I would like to make some kind of sorting and only view unique orders. Instead of a list like this:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
```

I would like it like this:

```
1
2
3
```

My thought is then to use this number and be able to select that order and change its content. Would it be possible to return a list with only unique numbers?

Comment: you want only ids in result?

Comment: @PavanTeja Only the OrderID

Comment: Use var allOrders = db.OrderRows.Select(c =>  c.OrderID }).ToList().Distinct().OrderBy(p => p.OrderID) and you will get required result

Comment: Not clear what you wanting to actually display in the view. Do you want to group by the `OrderID` (and under each group display the records associated with that order ID (e.g. there might be 3 different `Product` and `Price` values) or do you just want the first `OrderRows` object for each unique OrderID?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I guess it's the latter option

Comment: That does not really make sense, but to do it you can use a `.GroupBy()` clause and then get the `FirstOrDefault()` in each group

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why dows that not make sense? Perhaps I'm thinking wrong here? If I have several orders, would it not be better then to just show one ID for that order?

Comment: Based on you model, you create an order and each order has many order items - e.g. Order 1 is for 2 pencils at $1.00 and 1 Note Pad at $2.50. So does it make sense to display Order 1 is 2 pencils only (i.e the note pad is not shown in the view?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke If not sure if i understand you all the way. Each item in the shopping cart will be one row in the OrderRows table and for each row in that is written in the OrderRows is a ID from the Orders. There could only be a unique Order id for all of the items in the shopping cart. So if I have a list of all that OrderID from the OrderRows table I can get a list and then select each order made and with that ID view all the items in that order. Would that not work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104263/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-front-back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Distinct()`  extension method

if you want unique orderIds

```
var allOrders = db.OrderRows.ToList().Select(o=>o.OrderID ).Distinct()
```

if you want unique orderIds with first order row

```
var allOrders=db.OrderRows.ToList().GroupBy(o=>o.OrderID ).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I get an error like this: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebShop_2.Models.OrderRows]'. What could be wrong?

Comment: Thanks, but now I get another error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__1`1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebShop_2.Models.OrderRows]'.

Comment: You want only group id in result or entire OrderRows ?

Comment: I just want a list of the OrderID like I show in my question: 1, 2, 3 and not 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3

Comment: I added the Order class if that could be of any help!?

Comment: show me the code where you assigning the result list.There might be a type missmatch

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 var allOrders = db.OrderRows.ToList();
 var distinctOrders=allOrders.Distinct();
 view(distinctOrders);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, What you want is a `GroupBy`

Your query goes like-

```
var allOrders=db.OrderRows.GroupBy(o=>o.Orders).ToList()
```

Rendering it to View-

```
@foreach(var order in allOrders) {

 <p>@order.Key.ID</p>

  foreach(var orderItem in order.ToList()){

    <ul>
      <li>@orderItem.ProductID, @orderItem.Price</li>
    </ul>
 }
}
```